# DB filesystem encryption

Tags: php, encryption

This is very common question everyone has but important. Is there any best tool which encrypts filesystem? Here my requirement is even if we log in to db we should see encrypted data only. It should be displayed decrypted data only in front end.

So any one please can you suggest me a better way for implementing this. I am using PHP in LAMP server.

Thanks in advance,
Shilpa

Comment: I think this link will helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574341/safest-lamp-encrypt-method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ya that's the better way.. But is there a tool such that i should not make major changes to coding and automatically db should encrypt while inserting and updating. I am not sure if such tool exists. Other main requirement is even we log in to db it should show encrypted data only but again how can we show that in front end.

Answer (score 0):

> Here my requirement is even if we log in to db we should see encrypted data only. It should be displayed decrypted data only in front end.

There are different layers where encryption can be applied. Given this specific requirement:

- At the physical disk level
- At the filesystem level
- At the database engine level
- At the application-that-talks-to-the-database level (**you are here**)

Filesystem encryption won't stop someone who logs into the database from seeing data. It just encrypts the entire filesystem volume.

That being said, check out [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/). It's designed for searchable encryption, but you don't need to implement searching if you don't need it.

Encrypt/decrypt at the application layer, keep your encryption keys out of the database, and for maximum security, keep the webserver on separate hardware from the database server.